# CSS Grid - Check if grid row has empty cells and fill

Tags: javascript, css

I wasn't able to find a solution for the following:

I've created a grid layout (320px each row), max 4 rows, changing rows via media queries.

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 320px;
    grid-template-rows: 50px;
    grid-auto-rows: 50px;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    grid-row-gap: 4px;
    grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}
```

I am filling this container with content from an API. The divs to fill into the container have two different sizes (320px by 300px) or (660px by 300px). Like a Masonry Layout with infinity scrolling. By design it has, depending on the content sometimes gaps in the layouts.

My question is: How can I check if a grid-row is empty and fill in a placeholder-div (company logo, ...).

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Add image to show issue
[image: grid issue]

Comment: it would be helpful if you added a full working example, so people can see exactly what the question is asking.

Comment: Post some example html, along with the relevant (“*[mcve]*”) code. We need to know what you’re working with in order to provide sensible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean this ?

```js
$(".container").each(function(index, el) {
  if ($(el).is(':empty')) $(el).html("is empty");
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 320px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  grid-row-gap: 4px;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container">test</div>
<div class="container">test</div>
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container">test</div>
```

Comment: thank you. This solution, is not applicable, since the divs will be generate from API. Question is updated with image to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to check if the dev is empty, for example

```
if ($('.classNameOne').html() == "") {
   //Do something useful here
});
```

Comment: thank you. This solution, is not applicable, since the divs will be generate from API. Question is updated with image to illustrate the issue.